# Why distance matrix api returning the status "ZERO_RESULTS" even coordinates are correctly mentioned?

Tags: location, distance, status, bing-maps, google-distancematrix-api

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "14.868924,79.873609" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "14.843799,79.862726" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

url for this above response is given below only change the API key to verify it.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=14.843799,79.862726&destinations=14.868924,79.873609&mode=walking&key=XXXX

Although bing distance calculation api is successfully returning distance for this same coordinates.

Comment: Is your issue with the Bing Maps distance matrix service or Google Maps?

Comment: Issue is with Google distance matrix api

Comment: Did you get it solved?

Comment: Yes, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this issues to Google issue tracker and after that they fixed it within 1 month approximately.

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/38478121

Thanks